# How to reply with a function from another file in discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to reply a function from another file called "blockchain.py" but when I tried to await for `ctx.reply(blq.blockchain_connection)` it gives me this on Discord:

```
<function blockchain_connection at 0x000001922A5AEEF0>
```

The code is:

```
# bot = scrt.bot
bot   = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
login = 0

blq.tokens_dict

# Login
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global login
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    login = 1
    my_background_task.start()

# Coin Price Command
@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx, arg1):
    
    if blq.tokens_dict == blq.tokens_dict:
      blq.blockchain_connection
    else:
        await ctx.reply("The token " + str(arg1) +  " is not in the token list, if you want to add " + str(arg1) + " to the list please use the command : " + '\n' + "!add_token and insert key and value with an space on each")
        
@bot.command()
async def add_token(ctx, key, value):
    global tokens_dict

    if(key in blq.tokens_dict.keys()):
        await ctx.reply('I already have this token on my list, please add another Contract or another Value')
    else:
        blq.tokens_dict[key] = value
```

This other file (blockchain) has a dict and this function:

```
async def blockchain_connection(ctx, arg1):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/' + tokens_dict[arg1]) as r:
            res = await r.json()  # returns dict
            await ctx.reply(res['data']['price'])
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ctx.reply(blq.blockchain_connection)`? The issue is that the content of your reply is a reference to a function, not the return of a function, so that's why you're getting the weird-looking output (the string representation of the function).

Comment: I said "i tryied"

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I am asking where in your code you are calling the `reply` method and if you could post that code snippet. The problem is that you're passing a function as an argument, but it's a bit difficult to correct without seeing the context in which you are calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is here:

```py
# Coin Price Command
@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx, arg1):
    
    if blq.tokens_dict == blq.tokens_dict:
      blq.blockchain_connection
    else:
        await ctx.reply("The token " + str(arg1) +  " is not in the token list, if you want to add " + str(arg1) + " to the list please use the command : " + '\n' + "!add_token and insert key and value with an space on each")
```

`blq.blockchain_connection` is a function, receiving two arguments, which are named the same. It looks like you have to call it like so:

```py
# Coin Price Command
@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx, arg1):
    
    if blq.tokens_dict == blq.tokens_dict:
      await blq.blockchain_connection(ctx, arg1)
    else:
        await ctx.reply("The token " + str(arg1) +  " is not in the token list, if you want to add " + str(arg1) + " to the list please use the command : " + '\n' + "!add_token and insert key and value with an space on each")
```

This will actually call the function, which then internally (conditionally) calls `ctx.reply(...)` with the message you actually want to send.